# How to mock strings constants in android?

Tags: android, junit, mocking, android-productflavors

I have a use case where different flavors in android have different values of Strings. For eg:

```
Flavor1:
  public static final String CODE = "A";

Flavor2:
  public static final String CODE = "B";
```

There is a single class which uses them and whose test case is in the main directory. Now I cannot test it because the test fails in run for one flavor. Is there a way to mock this? Or any other way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Just declare public static final String CODE globaly, and then use:

```
Flavor1:
        CODE = "A";
Flavor2:
        CODE = "B";
```